# Avoid warn messages ‘schema.registry.url’ was supplied but isn’t a known config on kafka configuration

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I’m using spring-kakfa and I’m having this warn messages in logs:

```
WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig The configuration 'schema.registry.url' was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

In my Java configuration class I set this configuration:

```
config.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, kafkaGenericConfiguration.getSchemaRegistryUrl());
```

And in my YAML configuration file, I try several configuration types but it keep getting error…

```
spring: 
  kakfa:
    properties: 
      schema.registry.url: "http://localhost:8081"
    default:
      producer:
        configuration: 
          schema.registry.url: "http://localhost:8081"
    producer: 
      properties: 
        schema.registry.url: "http://localhost:8081"
```

Could you please advice how to solve this error?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't an error; it's a warning. Other than it causing extra logs, what is preventing your code from working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the property at the top level sets it for all components, including the admin, for which it clearly has no relevance; so remove that one.

I agree that the consumer and producer logs are annoying, but I can see why they want to log unexpected properties, in case of typos; but it is common to use consumer and producer configs to configure serializers and deserializers.

So, it's hard to know what is the best thing to do.

I suggest you open an issue against the kafka-clients to see if you can get some traction there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when you have supplied schema-registry url property, but does not use proper serializer and de-serializer which requires schema-registry.

For example: if you are using ByteArrayDeserializer, it does not require schema-registry and hence the warning displayed.